# How to generate ResearchGate icon in an elegant way?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Is it possible to reproduce the icon above under the following requirements

1. Ability to customize both of the foreground and background color
2. Ability to control the margins by shrinking or expanding them
3. Very similar font design

The total size of the icon should be controllable

Comment: You should consider using something like Inkscape to trace the raster graphic into a vectorized format where you can tweak things the way you like and then export it as a PDF for your use-case.

Comment: faking compoany logos is generally liable to be a trademark infringement it is much better to use the supplied logo with `\includegraphics` (if you just asked for putting  letters in a square without mentioning the company, that would be different)

Comment: Per [their term of service](https://www.researchgate.net/terms-of-service), "… the logos … are protected by copyright, trademark, and other intellectual property laws in multiple jurisdictions. For information about protecting Intellectual Property on the Service, please see our [Intellectual Property Policy](https://www.researchgate.net/ip-policy).", so @DavidCarlisle is definitely right on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fontawesome5` with LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\definecolor{aqua}{RGB}{0,208,187}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{1in}{!}{\textcolor{aqua}{\faResearchgate}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or `academicons` with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\definecolor{aqua}{RGB}{0,208,187}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{1in}{!}{\textcolor{aqua}{\aiResearchGateSquare}}
\end{document}
```

[image]